# Having a hard time building an aggregate SQL query

Tags: sql, request, aggregation

I am new at SQL and have a pretty good knowledge of basic stuff but I am stuck with my request.

My request gets me te following table (except for the last column on the right end side):

| Team | Variable | Date | Value | Column_I_need_to_add |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | aa | 2022/05/01 | 100 | 0 |
| A | aa | 2022/06/01 | 25 | 0 |
| A | aa | 2022/07/01 | 580 | 0 |
| A | ad | 2022/08/01 | 50 | 605 |
| B | aa | 2021/05/01 | 75 | 0 |
| B | aa | 2021/06/01 | 110 | 0 |
| B | aa | 2021/07/01 | 514 | 0 |
| B | ad | 2021/08/01 | 213 | 624 |

What I cannot turn my head around, is how to code for the last column that fills rows for the ad variable by summing values of the aa variables of the same team but only for the two months prior to the date of the ad variable.

Here is the script I have so far, that gets me the first four columns:

```sql
SELECT
 
    team.Team, 

    Var.Variable, 

    TO_DATE(Var.Year||'-'||LPAD(Var.Month,2,'00')||'-'||'01','YYYY-MM-DD')AS Date , 

    Var.value 

FROM table1 as Var

join table2 as team

on Var.code=team.code
---This last join with table3 is only there to add other columns that are not relevant to this problem.
---join table3 as detail_var on Var.variable=detail_var.code_var
```

Comment: Please do not post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of code or data. No one can copy/paste data from a picture. As explained in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
Sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not content with the previous answer, with OUTER APPLY, as understood from further reading. So had to do a bit of further grinding and this is what I came up with (Now for Postgres 13).

It is cleaner and does the job in a conciser fashion. I've also added a [`FIDDLE LINK`](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mmDFMRHatLm4jpYacPYtDe/0). If you want to see the previous answer please look at the edit versions.

```
SELECT
  team.Team
  ,var.Variable
  ,var.Date
  ,var.value
  ,CASE
    WHEN var.Variable='ad' THEN 
      (SELECT sum(value) FROM table1
       WHERE 
          (TO_DATE(Year||'-'||LPAD(Month::varchar(2),2,'0')||'-'||'01','YYYY-MM-DD')
              BETWEEN (var.Date - INTERVAL '2 month') AND var.Date)
          AND Variable = 'aa'
          AND code = var.code)
    ELSE null
  END as past2monthsValue
FROM (
  -- this sub query to change Year & Month to Date Type Value
  -- this Date Type Value (Date) will be used to compare dates
  -- (var.Date) in the above sub-query
  SELECT
    code,
    Variable,
    TO_DATE(Year||'-'||LPAD(Month::varchar(2),2,'0')||'-'||'01','YYYY-MM-DD') AS Date,
    value  
  FROM table1    
) var

JOIN table2 AS team ON var.code=team.code
```

Comment: This is specific to mysql... i.e. use of MySQL functions like CURDATE / INTERVAL

Comment: Check the appropriate syntax for your sql engine

Comment: Dear Nazim, Thank you for answering. However, if I understand correctly your request it does not take into consideration several things, I actually need to filter my aggregation based on the variable (here: "aa") and sum the values. With regard to the date, I cannot use current date but the date corresponding the the "ad" variable, which can change.

Comment: Can you provide the source table data for the expected result above?

Comment: I updated the post so that the table can be copied! Sorry, this is my first post ever. I start with several tables and create the table above, and I need to add the last column.

Comment: Your query to generate the above results would need modification and hence, your query that gives the above results (except for the last column) would be the starting point. Can you share?

Comment: The post now includes my intial request!

Comment: Great. This looks like the server will assess square number of rows in the table if you don't filter it first. You might have to rethink to run it on displayed rows only. I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: Answer Updated. Outer Apply is the Solution I believe. Do upvote and mark if answer is acceptable :)

Comment: David... I have updated the answer based on further reading. Included a working fiddle in Postgres 13, with output matching your expected results. Have a look [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mmDFMRHatLm4jpYacPYtDe/0) (Didn't actually need OUTER APPLY)